# SQL - Group By w/ LIMIT or TOP

Tags: sql

I have a simple select query which returns a summary of SaleAmount grouped by CustomerName.

Here's is an example of the results from the query:

```
Customer Name | SaleAmount (in millions)
-----------------------------------------
John Doe - 10.5
Jane Doe - 8
Don Johnson - 7
Bill Joel - 6
Ron Swanson - 5
Bret Faker - 4
Johnny Apple - 3
El Merfud - 2
```

What I would then like to get from that result is just the top 5 results. I am not very good with SQL so I'm struggling to find how to do this by playing around with it and not sure how to word it for a Google search either. If anyone can help that would be awesome.

Edit:
Here is the SQL query to get the results I have above.

```
SELECT customer.FullName, SUM(sale.SalesAmount)
FROM sale
LEFT JOIN customer
    ON customer.id = sale.customerid
GROUP BY customer.FullName
```

So it's actually pulling from the sale table and joining the customer. I just want to grab the first 5 results from that query. I should have been more specific.

Comment: Do a subquery and select top 10 from the sub query.  If you have your code that generates the above please post and we can provide an example

Comment: `LIMIT` and `TOP` are used in different RDBMS systems. So that information is important (which SQL are you using?).

Comment: Select DISTINCT TOP (5) Customer Name, SaleAmount from Tablename;

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which SQL engine it is. I'm actually doing this in FileMaker Pro 16. I have the reference for SQL but I don't see where it specifies which engine it runs:
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fm16_sql_reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server or MS Access:

```
SELECT TOP 5 CustomerName, SaleAmount
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY SaleAmount DESC
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT CustomerName, SaleAmount
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY SaleAmount DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `OFFSET FETCH` in ANSI SQL

```
SELECT CustomerName, SaleAmount
FROM your_table
ORDER BY SaleAmount 
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```